# Images not found when testing website on mobile

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, web, png

I am attempting to test a website created in Dreamweaver on my phone. I have a copy of the folder with all the html/images in my Dropbox. Let's say that filename is "website". Inside of "website" I have a folder called "images" with all the images for the site, as well as my stylesheet.

My html files link to images like this:   src="images/pic1.png"

A couple of the images are in the CSS, and are referenced like this: url(images/pic2.png)

On my computer, this works and all the images show up. On my phone in a folder that is an EXACT COPY, all of the images are broken links.

Anybody know what could be causing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the capitalization. Some browsers can load images even if they were not correctly referenced. For example I could say load: `Image.png` and it may load it correctly even if it's called `image.png`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your Dropbox is on your computer, and not on your phone. Based on what you said, you are accessing the images locally, therefore the phone doesn't see files on your computer. Try transporting all images from Dropbox to the server where you host your website. Then the phone should be able to see the images.

Comment: Got it working thanks to the above comment. I'm not sure why this question got downvoted so much. Now I can't post any other questions I have. It seems kind of pointless to not allow me to ask another question because I asked one question that got downvoted for no reason...